# Advice on how to optimize this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query works fine, it returns the information of every house it also returns if it has due , how much, and the status of every month of the current year.
each month has a subquery that calculates an ammount and returns a number.
everything works fine jut that, it takes a lot to procces....,
the query has the exact information i need to bring, so how can i optimize this for working faster or im i doing things wrong and this query doenst work at all.

any advice how can i optimize it.
Thanks a lot.

```
SELECT tbl_torre.idtorre,
       tbl_deptos.iddepto,
       tbl_torre.torre,
       tbl_deptos.depto,
       tbl_deptos.id_eup,
       tbl_deptos.entregado,

  (SELECT SUM(cantidadapagar+interes-descuento)
   FROM tbl_incomens
   WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
     AND MONTH(datebelong) < MONTH(NOW())
     AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
     AND payed = 0
     AND idconcep IN (1,
                      2,
                      3)) AS month_due,

  (SELECT count(idincome)
   FROM tbl_incomens
   WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
     AND MONTH(datebelong) < MONTH(NOW())
     AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
     AND payed = 0
     AND idconcep IN (1,
                      2,
                      3)) AS num_due,

  (SELECT SUM(cantidadapagar+interes-descuento)
   FROM tbl_incomens
   WHERE DATE(datebelong) < DATE(NOW())
     AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
     AND payed = 0
     AND idconcep IN (1,
                      2,
                      3)) AS total_due,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 1
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 1
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS jan,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 2
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 2
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS feb,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 3
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 3
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS mar,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 4
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 4
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS abr,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 5
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 5
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS may,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 6
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 6
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS jun,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 7
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 7
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS jul,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 8
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 8
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS ago,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 9
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 9
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS sep,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 10
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 10
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS oct,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 11
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 11
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS nov,

  (SELECT CONCAT(
                   (SELECT ROUND(SUM(payed))
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 12
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)),'@',
                   (SELECT COUNT(idincome)
                    FROM tbl_incomens
                    WHERE YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW())
                      AND MONTH(datebelong) = 12
                      AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
                      AND idconcep IN (1,2,3)))) AS dic
FROM tbl_torre
INNER JOIN tbl_deptos ON tbl_torre.idtorre = tbl_deptos.idt
```

Comment: Consider starting with something simpler

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query does would all help.

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-queries seem to be using the same couple of tables with the same WHERE clauses over and over. Why not run one query to gather the filtered data you need (rather than running it over for each SUM or COUNT), and then use the filtered data in the main query. I'm not going recreate the whole query you posted, but you can build on this idea to complete it from the rest.

For example, your first 3 sub-queries all pull from the tbl_incomens table, using the same WHERE clause. So, gather that data first into a table variable, or temp table using that WHERE clause. Then, you write the main query to use the temp table instead:

```
declare @temp_tbl_incomes table (cantidadapagar decimal(14,2), interes decimal(14,2), descuento decimal(14,2), idincome int)
insert into @temp_tbl_incomes (cantidadapagar, interes, descuento, idincome)
select cantidadapagar, interes, descuento, idincome
from tbl_incomens
WHERE DATE(datebelong) < DATE(NOW())
    AND tbl_incomens.iddpt = tbl_deptos.iddepto
    AND payed = 0
    AND idconcep IN (1,
                    2,
                    3)

SELECT tbl_torre.idtorre,
       tbl_deptos.iddepto,
       tbl_torre.torre,
       tbl_deptos.depto,
       tbl_deptos.id_eup,
       tbl_deptos.entregado,

  (SELECT SUM(cantidadapagar+interes-descuento)
   FROM @temp_tbl_incomes) AS month_due,

  (SELECT count(idincome)
   FROM @temp_tbl_incomes) AS num_due,

  (SELECT SUM(cantidadapagar+interes-descuento)
   FROM @temp_tbl_incomes) AS total_due
FROM tbl_torre
INNER JOIN tbl_deptos ON tbl_torre.idtorre = tbl_deptos.idt
```

In the end you may have 3 or 4 different queries that just build data into temp tables, and then you main query references those 3 or 4 filtered tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very hard to follow, but I think you should start with conditional aggregation.  Here is an example for the first column:

```
SELECT t.idtorre, d.iddepto, t.torre, d.depto, d.id_eup, d.entregado,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(i.datebelong) < MONTH(NOW()) AND
                     i.payed = 0 AND
                     i.idconcep IN (1, 2, 3)
                THEN i.cantidadapagar + i.interes - i.descuento)
           END) as month_due,
       . . .    
FROM tbl_torre t INNER JOIN
     tbl_deptos d
     ON t.idtorre = d.idt LEFT JOIN
     tbl_incomens i
     ON YEAR(datebelong) = YEAR(NOW()) AND
        i.iddpt = d.iddepto
GROUP BY t.idtorre, d.iddepto, t.torre, d.depto, d.id_eup, d.entregado;
```